# Question regarding $H^0$ of stable vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces, holomorphic-bundles

Let $M$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$ and $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle with the property that for any proper holomorphic subbundle $F$ we have $deg(F)/rank(F) < deg(E)/rank(E)$ then E is called a stable holomorphic vector bundle.

> Hitchin states in one of his papers that $H^0(M, End (E)) ≈ \mathbb C$ since E is stable.

How does one prove this statement?
I'm new to this subject and I couldn't find a way to attempt this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72158/endomorphisms-of-stable-vector-bundles-over-a-riemann-surface

Comment: Also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137779/are-stable-holomorphic-bundles-over-compact-k%C3%A4hler-manifolds-simple

Comment: Look here at the Proof of Proposition 1 http://www.math.columbia.edu/~chaoli/docs/StableVectorBundles.html

Comment: In some of the links you posted I notice that they are using slope for image of a vector bundle which is just a coherent sheaf and maynot be a vector bundle. What is the notion of degree and rank of a coherent sheaf?

Comment: You can define stability in terms of the reduced Hilbert polynomial for coherent sheaves on any projective scheme, and in particular for vector bundles over a riemann surface, you can get a notion of slope (which is the slope of the reduced Hilbert polynomial as a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q$). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_vector_bundle#Generalizations

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition**

Let $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over $M$, then $$E \ \text{stable}\Longrightarrow E \ \text{simple}\Longrightarrow E \ \text{indecomposable}$$ where a vector bundle $E$ is simple if $End(E)\cong\mathbb C$ and it is indecomposable if can not be written as a direct sum of proper subbundles.

**Proof**

Let $E$ be a stable bundle and let $f\in \ $End$(E)$ be a non-zero homomorphism then it has to be necessarily an isomorphism (this result is quite standard in the theory of stable bundles). Thus End$(E)$ is a field, which contains $\mathbb{C}$ as its sub-field of scalar endomorphism. Then for any $f\in \ $End$(E)$, the sub-field $\mathbb{C}(f)\subset \ $End$(E)$ is a commutative field, and the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem implies that $f$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, this shows that $f\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence End$(E)\simeq\mathbb{C}$, in paricular Aut$(E)\simeq\mathbb{C}^{*}$. Moreover if $E\simeq E_1\oplus E_2$ then Aut$(E)$ contains $\mathbb{C}^{*}\times\mathbb{C}^{*}$ and thus $E$ can not be simple, neither stable.

With this proposition in mind, it should be clear why $H^0(M,End(E))\cong\mathbb C$ if $E$ is a stable bundle.